# How to use generic in Stack data structure?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

I have implemented a simple Stack in Java  and it works. It uses *Node* class for holding the stack int values. Now, I'm planning another class *NodeWithMin* that should contain the node in concern and the minimum values from the node to bottom. That means when I will get the top node of the stack I will have node and the minimum value of the stack.

I want to use generic with the *Stack* class to switch whichever class ( *Node* / *NodeWithMin*) that I would like to plug with it. So, finally it will be something -

```
public class myStack extends Stack< Node or NodeWithMin >{

}
```

Where Stack needs to be

```
class Stack<T>{

}
```

Let me know if you need further clarification of the question. I understand inside of  some methods in the *Stack* class needs to changed. Any advice on how can I do that ? THANK YOU.

```
import java.util.*;

class Node {

    public Node above;
    public Node below;
    public int data;

    public Node(int data) {

        this.data = data;
    }

}

class NodeWithMin {

    public NodeWithMin above;
    public NodeWithMin below;

    public int data;
    public int min;

    public NodeWithMin(int data , int min){

        this.data = data;
        this.min = min;
    }

}


class Stack {

    private int capacity;
    public Node top;
    public Node bottom;
    public int size;

    HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public Stack ( int cap ){

        this.top = null;
        this.bottom = null;
        this.capacity = cap;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public static int randomInt(int n) {

        return (int) (Math.random() * n);
    }

    public static int randomIntInRange(int min, int max) {

        return randomInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
    }

    public boolean isFull() { 
        return capacity == size; 
    }

    public void join (Node newNode, Node stackTop) {

        // not empty stack 
        if ( stackTop != null ){

            stackTop.above = newNode;
        }

        // if the new node is not null
        // previous top is now below of the inserted node which is the current top 
        if ( newNode != null){

            newNode.below = stackTop;
        }
    }

    public boolean push(int v) {

        if (size >= capacity) 
            return false;

        size++;
        Node n = new Node(v);
        if (size == 1) bottom = n;
        join(n, top);

        // define the new top 
        top = n;

        // pushing is sucessful 
        return true;
    }

    public int min(){

        if ( top == null) return -1;

        Node curr = this.top;
        int min =-1 ; 

        System.out.println("\n\n");
        while( curr != null){

            hashSet.add(curr.data);
            curr = curr.below;
        }

        System.out.println();
        min = Collections.min(hashSet);

        return min; 
    }

    public int pop() {

        Node t = top;
        top = top.below;
        size--;
        return t.data;
    }

    public int peek (){

        Stack myStack = this; 
        return myStack.top.data ;

    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
        return size == 0; 
    }

    public int removeBottom() {

        Node b = bottom;
        bottom = bottom.above;
        if (bottom != null) bottom.below = null;
        size--;
        return b.data;
    }

    public void display(){

        if ( top == null) return;

        Node curr = this.top;
        int min =-1 ; 

        System.out.println("\n\n");
        while( curr != null){

            System.out.println( curr.data);

            curr = curr.below;

            if ( curr != null){

                System.out.println("↑");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ){

        // System.out.println("\nMy stack is here \n");
        Stack s = new Stack(5);

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++){
            s.push( randomIntInRange(0, 100) );
        }

        s.display();
        System.out.println("the min of the stack is =  "+ s.min());

    }

}
```

Comment: A quick google search gives: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0200__Generics/GenericclassStack.htm. Hopefully, that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As you see, I can get the minimum, but, I'm also thinking it little different way. So, you when I will peek() the top, it should also give me the minimum of  the Stack with the top values. 

I can implement it without generics, but, I would like to learn it. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you should have your Node and NodeWithMin implement a common interface, and then your Stack could work with that interface.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if `NodeWithMin` does the same basic thing as `Node`, plus it has the Min stuff. So I'd make `NodeWithMin` extend `Node`. Then you could declare MyStack as:

```
public class myStack extends Stack< ? extends Node > {
...
}
```

`MyStack` will now work with either `Node` or `NodeWithMin`.

As for `Stack`, the most notable problem is that it is written to explicitly depend on instances of `Node`. That's an issue because you say you want `Stack` to be generic, able to take any `T`. So you'll have to keep all of the `T` instances in the correct order without expecting them to remember who comes before or after, and that's inconsistent with what you're trying to do with `NodeWithMin`.

So I think you need to rethink just how generic you want this stuff to be. If `Stack` should really be completely generic, i.e. it should be able to keep any kind of object in LIFO order, then `MyStack` will have to override large portions of the methods in `Stack` in order to make use of what it knows about `Node`. OTOH, if all you really want to do is keep a bunch of `Node` (or subtypes thereof) objects in LIFO order, then ditch `Stack` completely and just go straight to `MyStack`.

Oh BTW, your use of `HashSet` is troublesome. Since you instantiate it once, you run the risk of it keeping stuff around that no longer exists in the `Stack`, i.e. you could pop the current min, but the `min()` method would keep returning it. Better to make it a local variable in the `min()` method since that's the only place it's used.

Further, in order to use the `Collections.min()` method, all of the objects in the `Stack` must implement `Comparable`, and that argues against using a generic `T`. You will probably want to move the `min()` method to `MyStack` (assuming that you change `Node` to implement `Comparable`).

Comment: Thanks for writing in so details.